# modular exponentiation $14^{20} \pmod{33}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I find 14^20 mod 33 ?

I tried writing 14^20 as 14^(2+4+8+6) but still no simplification.

Should I just check all the power of 14 mod 33 and hope that some of them give nice numbers (1 or 2)

What is a good method ?

Comment: You should LaTeX your question.

Comment: Consider successive multiplication and reduction.

Comment: @José should we just get rid of modular arithmetic then ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Are you sure that this is a comment concerning *this* question?

Comment: it's regarding your own comments so hopefully...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider $14^{20}$ mod $3$ and mod $11$. Use Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

By [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), as $(14,33)=1$, and $\phi(33)=20$, so $14^{20}\equiv1\pmod{33}$.